# Storing info in NSNotification Center for observer

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

Im trying to add an observer to the Notification Center which will execute a method. That method should extract some data from the NSNotification sent.
The info which will be passed is in a `[String]`. The sender doesnt know about this data and can therefor not add it to the userInfo field when posting to NSNotificationCenter. So far my code looks like this:

Adding observer along with the intended data

```
global.notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "test", name: "gotClientToken", object: [type, id, region])
```

Posting the notification from a separate class, with no access to the data needed.

```
global.notificationCenter.postNotificationName("gotUserToken", object: nil)
```

The variables, from which the data being sent with the notification is drawn, will change, hence I want it attached to the notification and not simply saved in a variable to be accessed later.

Maybe there an entirely different way of doing it? I'm not sure...

Comment: It has to be saved somewhere. Why not save it in the only place where it is needed, the receiver? Save it in a dictionary. Use the notification names as keys for the dictionary.

Comment: The method which adds the observer and the method which posts the notification are both used multiple times with different data sets, but the notification names stay the same... But I'm going to try your dictionary idea with a change or two - thanks :)

Comment: Problem is, the sender has no idea that it should be "AwesomeString", and cannot access the observer because by then, the data would have changed. And as far as I know, data should be sent via userInfo instead of via Object when posting a notification. The Object should be a reference to the senders object

Comment: You're right. I'll remove the comment.